# Get text content of captured selector in artillery test

Tags: cheerio, artillery

I have an artillery test which I'd like to have check a title on a page to ensure that it is correct. I'm able to capture the element nicely using

```
      capture:
         - selector: "#BodyContent_lblWelcome"
           as: title
```

This element is a `span` and I'd like to check what text is in that span. I've tried various combinations of `attr` such as `text`, `value`, `innerHTML` and I've tried logging properties off the capture like so

```
  - log: "{{title}}"
  - log: "{{title.value}}"
```

The first log here prints something like `[Object: null prototype] { id: 'BodyContent_lblWelcome' }` but the second prints nothing. How can I get at the content of the node without resorting to a regex or xpath match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't currently as it only works with attributes, from [the code](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/blob/3158660f1df3912b829f94e0af59a084c7ffd056/core/lib/engine_util.js#L522):

```
function extractCheerio(doc, expr, opts) {
  let $ = cheerio.load(doc);
  let els = $(expr);
  let i = 0;
  //snip...
  return els.slice(i, i + 1).attr(opts.attr);
}
```